# Classic ASP, problem logging in to SQL Server using Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I failed to connect using this connection string

```
strConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Initial Catalog=fsw;SERVER=HARDIXP\hardi;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC
>   Drivers (0x80004005) [Microsoft][ODBC
>   SQL Server Driver][DBMSLPCN]SQL Server
>   does not exist or access denied.

I can connect fine using SQL Server Management Studio. On the "Connect to Server" dialog, I have

Server Name: HARDIXP
Authentication: Windows Authentication

After it is connected, the server looks like this

HARDIXP (SQL Server 10.0.2531 - HARDIXP\hardi)

If I don't specify the server name, the error will be

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL
>   Server (0x80040E4D) Login failed for
>   user 'HARDIXP\IUSR_GEOFFREYXP'.

Note that it is trying a different user, probably because the database was first set up for Geoffrey, not Hardi.

How can I connect to my local SQL Server from this Classic ASP code?

EDIT: I am on Windows XP, IIS 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is running on windows.

The ASP process needs to be running as a windows authenticated user that has access to the 
database. Just set the [application pool on the website to have this identity's credentials](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/).

Comment: Yup it is Windows XP, so I need to configure it in the IIS?

Comment: Thanks btw Preet but the link you sent is for a newer version of IIS, I am still using IIS 5.1